# Electron spin and energy levels of hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Shankar's quantum mechanics book he says the spin of electron doesn't change the energy levels of hydrogen atom(page 397, 2nd edition). How doesn't spin(being a form of angular momentum) change the energy levels? The total Hamiltonian has a piece for spin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we only account for the coulomb interaction which is the strongest one relevant to the hydrogen atom then the Hamiltonian won’t have any spin dependence. But that’s only an approximation, a very good one nonetheless.

However, if we look carefully enough we see that you are right. Energy does in fact depend on spin. For further details, look at [spin-orbit interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93orbit_interaction), a relativistic effect. But this is small compared to the coulomb interaction energy. To be precise, $\sim 10^5$ times smaller. This extra energy due to spin-orbit causes the spectral lines to spilt. But only when looked at with enough resolution. Hence it is also called as the **fine structure**.

[image]

You can look at [this lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/lecture-notes/MIT8_06S18ch2.pdf) from MIT-OCW 8.06 or [this](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydfin.html) hyperphysics page on the fine structure for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Electron spin does not appear in the Schroedinger equation. It does not affect it's single electron solutions. Many-electron solutions are affected only via Pauli exclusion. However, the Schroedinger equation is a non-relativistic approximation. In the Dirac equation spin impacts the solutions.

Comment: The total Hamiltonian appears to be the sum two Hamiltonians: Orbital and spin. Shouldn't the total Hamiltonian enter the Schrödinger equation?

Comment: *It does not affect it's single electron solutions* This is incorrect. The fine structure is modelled in QM via the spin-orbit interaction which in fact affects the single electron solutions of Schrodinger equation.

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish Spin-orbit coupling is not part of the Schroedinger equation.

Comment: Schrodinger equation is just $H|\psi\rangle=i\partial_t|\psi\rangle$ and the Hamiltonian $H$ depends on how one models it. So I don’t know why you say *Spin-orbit coupling is not part of the Schroedinger equation.* you may look at the lecture notes attached in my answer that shows how one can incorporate it.